# how to get google ranking info for all pages of my site?

Tags: seo

is there a tool to get google's ranking number for all pages of my site?

i know you can install Google toolbar. It shows the ranking for each page you visit. But for my own site, i have thousands of pages. Is there a way to know all their rankings? (so i can know which page i should work more. afaik google analytics or webmaster tools doesn't give this info. (i use them both))

Comment: for any looking for answer too, this might be helpful  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=025cf34022c63245

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try giving this a shot:

http://www.intenseblog.com/tutorials/check-pagerank-of-all-pages-within-site.html

Otherwise, the only solutions I'm aware of would be browser plugins.

Answer (score 2):

> i know you can install Google toolbar. It shows the ranking for each page you visit

no it doesn't! i show a ***meaningless*** green toolbar pagerank bar (commonly also known ad thought-cancer bar) it's sh*t ignore it.

go to **google webmaster tools** -> **Your site on the web** -> **Search queries** -> **Top pages** (it's a tab, not on the left hand side but in the main area at the top)

Comment: thanks. That's useful info too.